# how to setup a timer in Python?

Tags: python, time

I would like to create a timer in Python. After I run the .py class I would like a method to be called every hour in 12 hour period, after 12 hours end the program closes. How can I do this?

I want something like:

```
    if time == 12 hours:
    finish
    else:
    if 1 hours passed:
    methodFoo()
```

Comment: "threading" module has a class "Timer" for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `time.sleep()`

```
import time

hours = 0
while hours < 12:
    methodFoo()
    hours += 1
    time.sleep(3600) # seconds

print('finish after 12 hours')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need convert `if..else` to `while` and define the function
Please to refer to this[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/)